# Binding String Collection to ListView, Windows Forms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, data-binding, collections

I have a StringCollection that I want to One Way Bind to a ListView.  As in, the ListView should display the contents of the StringCollection.  I will be removing items from the collection programatically so they don't need to interact with it through the ListView.

I have a Form with a Property, like so -->

```
public DRIUploadForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        lvwDRIClients.DataBindings.Add("Items", this.DirtyDRIClients, "DirtyDRIClients");
    }

private StringCollection _DirtyDRIClients;
public StringCollection DirtyDRIClients 
    { 
        get
        {
            return _DirtyDRIClients;
        }
        set
        {
            _DirtyDRIClients = Settings.Default.DRIUpdates;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cannot actually bind to a ListView control, as it does not support binding. You need to add the items programmatically. You can however bind to a ListBox, although as others have said you cannot bind strings directly, you need to create a wrapper for them. Something like this...

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    List<Item> items = new List<Item>
    {
        new Item { Value = "One" },
        new Item { Value = "Two" },
        new Item { Value = "Three" },
    };

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        listBox1.DataSource = items;
        listBox1.DisplayMember = "Value";
    }
}

public class Item
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```